# Android encryption: Encrypted file size is less than original file

Tags: android, encryption

After encryption of video file the encrypted file size  is less than the original file(usually half of original file size). So am not able to decrypt it.
My code for encryption is..

```
public static void encryptMe(String  vidName)
{
    try {
        File rawData = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "HSDownloads");
        File fiss = new File(rawData, vidName);
        Log.d(TAG,"input file  "+fiss.toString());
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fiss);

        File encreptedFileDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "HSEncript");

        if(encreptedFileDirectory.exists())
        {

        }
        else
        {
            encreptedFileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        File outfile = new File(encreptedFileDirectory,vidName);
        OutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(outfile);

        byte[] skey = AppUtiles.generateKey("qwertyuiopasdfgh");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");


        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128*1024];
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            Log.d(TAG,"inside while loop encryptMe()"+(count = in.read(buffer)));
        }
       out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"exception encryption >"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    finally 
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Inside finally   ");
    }
}
```

For decryption and streaming video,
 am using libmedia jar .

```
public void playENCVideo(String path) {
    try {
        Cipher decipher = null;

        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");


        byte[] key = AppUtiles.generateKey("qwertyuiopasdfgh");
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);

        mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();

        mServer.setCipher(decipher);
        mServer.start();

        path = mServer.getURL(path);

        vvPlayer.setVideoPath(path);
        vvPlayer.start();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "InvalidKeyException  ");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException  ");

    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NoSuchPaddingException  ");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOEXCEPTION   ");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Genral exceptin");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you read from the input file in your log statement:

```
Log.d(TAG,"inside while loop encryptMe()"+(count = in.read(buffer)));
```

is never encrypted. Only the data read in the while loop is written to the `out` stream

Edit:
Don't do read 2:

```
                   read 1
                   VVVV
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);          
    Log.d(TAG,"inside while loop encryptMe()"+(count = in.read(buffer)));
}                                                         ^^^^
                                                          read 2
```

Comment: out.write(buffer, 0, count); is writing data, inside while loop, the line above you highlighted.

Comment: You do two reads (one in the while loop & one in the log statement) .. but you only write one of them .. You are leaking every second read, and thus end up with a file of half size ..

Comment: Thank you, My problem solved. Also Am trying to download and play video in my app.In order to play video, only in my app am encrypting it. But code am using taking huge time. How can i reduce encryption time for above code.